# inherit class react in razor page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, razor-pages

i have a razor page and i want to render a class React.Component inside it. If i render a single page it works but if i import in the App class a Child component throw me the following error:

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string
> (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
> components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your
> component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up
> default and named imports.
>
> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a
> string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
> components) but got: object.

What did i miss to import Child correctly?Or i have to change React.createElement in order to have a class that is modularized?

**[EDIT] i just found out that i cannot use React.createElement for scripts that are module...so how can i do the same thing??**

App.jsx:

```
import { Child } from './Components/Child';

class App extends React.Component{

    componentDidMount() {
       
    }
    
    render() {
        console.log(this.props)
       
        const list = this.props.Property1;
        return (
            <div>
                <ul>
                    {list.map(item => (
                        <li key={item.name}>{item.name}</li>
                    ))}
                </ul>

                <Child></Child>
            </div>

            );
    }
     
}
```

Child.jsx

```
 export class Child extends React.Component {

        componentDidMount() {

        }

        render() {

            return (
                <div>
                    Sono il figlio del component padre  :  {this.props.data}
                </div>

            );
        }

    }
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@using Newtonsoft.Json;
@using SportData.Web.Models;
@using System.Web.Optimization;


@model SportContainer



<div id="App">
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/remarkable/1.7.1/remarkable.min.js"></script>


<script src="@Url.Content("~/js/app.jsx")" type="module" ></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/js/Components/Child.jsx")" type="module"></script>
<script>
    var modelObject = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model.sportList));
    ReactDOM.render(
        React.createElement(App, { Property1: modelObject }),
        document.getElementById("App")
    );
    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with the export statement in the Child.jsx component. You're using export class Child, but in your App.jsx component you're importing the component using **import { Child } from './Components/Child';**.

Try changing the import statement in App.jsx to

> import Child from './Components/Child';

In this case, you would only need to specify the default export (in this case Child) without curly braces.

Comment: Still same error.

Comment: make sure that the component being imported is a default export. If Child is not a default export, you need to add default before the class declaration:
 -> export default class Child extends React.Component

Comment: when i start the project the inspector's console cannot recognize export or module.export

Comment: this is the link to the other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75327014/reactjs-export-and-module-are-not-defined